# tar -xvzf [filename] creates an extra directory

Tags: 14.04, data-recovery, directory, tar, filezilla

I have a tar file in `/var/www/orbitcode/public_html/orbit.tar.gz` when I unzip it using `tar -xvzf orbit.tar.gz` a new `pub_html` directory is created.

The path of the extracted files is `/var/www/orbitcode/public_html/public_html/[extracted files]`.

Shouldn't the extracted files be in the `orbit` directory? Why is it creating a new `public_html` directory?

I am using ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you created `/var/www/orbitcode/public_html/orbit.tar.gz` you missed the message that told you

```
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
```

Use `tar tf /var/www/orbitcode/public_html/orbit.tar.gz` to list the member names.

To correct for the current situation (use `sudo` to taste),

```
cd /var/www/orbitcode/public_html
# Assume extracted files must replace current dir files
mv -v -f --target-directory=$PWD public_html/* public_html/.*
# rmdir FAILS on non-empty directories
rmdir public_html
```

Comment: I have executed the above steps. The extracted files are now in `/var/www/orbitcode/public_html`. But when i am accessing this through filezilla it still shows the extracted files in `/var/www/orbitcode/public_html/public_html/[extracted_files]`. I have also deleted the second public _html directory as told above. No reflection in Filezilla

Comment: I am sorry , it has reflected now. Took some time though.

Answer (score 2):

It happens presumably because you tarred the whole `public_html` directory and its name is in the archive.

You can use the `--strip-components` argument to cut off the head of the path when extracting.

In your case:

```
tar -xvzf --strip-components 1 orbit.tar.gz
```

To remove the `public_html/` and extract files directly into the current directory.

`1` in the above command stands for a single level in the extracted path.